# How I can make my belongsToMany relation in adonis.js

Tags: javascript, orm, relationship, adonis.js

I'm trying to make a relationship between two tables.
My relationship is belongsToMany between user => user_bet_match => matchs.
A user can have many user_bet_match and matchs can have many user_bet_match.

My database migration is :
Matchs table :

```
    this.create('matchs', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('round_id').unsigned()
      table.integer('league_id').unsigned()
      table.integer('hometeam_id').unsigned()
      table.integer('awayteam_id').unsigned()
      table.string('final_score_hometeam_goal')
      table.string('final_score_awayteam_goal')
      table.string('halftime_score_hometeam_goal')
      table.string('halftime_score_awayteam_goal')
      table.date('event_date')
      table.integer('event_timestamp')
      table.boolean('betailable').defaultTo(false)
      table.boolean('is_finish').defaultTo(false)
      table.timestamps()
    })
```

User table:

```
    this.create('users', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('username', 80).notNullable().unique()
      table.string('email', 254).notNullable().unique()
      table.string('password', 60).notNullable()
      table.timestamps()
    })
```

user_bet_match table :

```
    this.create('user_bet_match', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned()
      table.integer('match_id').unsigned()
      table.string('choice').notNullable()
      table.timestamps()
    })
```

My user model:

```
class User extends Model {
  static boot () {
    super.boot()

    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (userInstance) => {
      if (userInstance.dirty.password) {
        userInstance.password = await Hash.make(userInstance.password)
      }
    })
  }

  tokens () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Token')
  }
  match () {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Match').pivotTable('user_bet_match')
  }
```

My user bet match module:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')
const Database = use('Database')



class UserBetMatch extends Model {

  user () {
    return this.hasOne('App/Models/User')
  }
  matchs () {
    return this.hasOne('App/Models/Match')
  }
}

module.exports = UserBetMatch
```

And my matchs module:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Match extends Model {
  userbetmatchs () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/UserBetMatch')
  }
}

module.exports = Match
```

And when I make :

```
let k = user.match().fetch()
```

With this relation :

```
  match () {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Match').pivotTable('user_bet_match')
  }
```

It's returning me `sqlMessage: "Table 'bo7jjjccwliucibms5pf.matches' doesn't exist"`
But I never mention of a table "matches"..
I don't know why..

Comment: Can you please share your 3 models?

Comment: It's done, sorry @CrBast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you changed the name of the tables in the migration (by default with adonis cli : matches; user_bet_matches)

Try to use this in your models:

```js
static get table () {
    return 'matchs' // Your table name
}
```

^ https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/lucid#_table

Lucid does not take into account the migrations. 
It's therefore necessary to specify the name of the table if it is not the default one (with adonis cli).

*Don't hesitate to tell me if it's not fair.*

Comment: Oh nice it's working ! How do you know that the origin of the name of the table was 'matches' ? Thank's you !

Comment: You're welcome :). I executed this command : `adonis make:migration Match`. 
It's a recurring problem

Comment: Oh ok cool ! I know more about Adonis aha, (cool profile picture of Laink et terracid aha )